# Moving VS "Folders" section to Primary bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not sure what happened but the "Folders" view is on the left secondary bar.
It used to be with the primary bar on the right.
I am trying to combine it so I see the "Folders" on the Explorer view.

```
Version: 1.77.3 (Universal)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:19:37.325Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```

[image: Secondary bar]

[image: Primary bar]

Comment: Just drag the little underlined folders icon to the Explorer view and drop it.